# Issue in getting difference Date

Tags: android, date, datepicker, calendar

I only need Today and yesterday date and when other date is selected it should give error....I am getting every thing ok but there is small issue 
Here is my code:

```
  if (flag == 0) {
            if (getday(myCalendar.getTime()) == 1 || getday(myCalendar.getTime()) == 0) {
                setvisitdate();
            }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Selected date is not valid...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                flag = 0;
                new DatePickerDialog(FvrActivity.this, date,
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
```

here is method of getday:

```
 private int getday(Date selected_date) {

        Calendar selected_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        selected_cal .setTime(selected_date);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.getTime();
        long diffInMillisec = c.getTimeInMillis() - selected_cal.getTimeInMillis();
        long diffInDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(diffInMillisec);
        return (int) diffInDays;
  }
```

Suppose today's date is 21/11/2016...I just want to select 21 date and 20 and not 22 but here i can select 22 also..Thank you in advance for solving.

Comment: beetween 22 and 21 difference also one day. guess you can add .above() \ .belowe() check. also Date class will be enought. new Date() gets you current date, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this logic:

```
Calendar selected_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
selected_cal.setTime(selected_date);

//For next day                
Calendar nextDay = Calendar.getInstance();
nextDay.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);//Adding one day
nextDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);//Setting calendar for start hour of the day
nextDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);//Setting calendar for start minute of the day
nextDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);//Setting calendar for start second of the day

//For previous days
Calendar previousDay = Calendar.getInstance();
previousDay.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);//Adding one day
previousDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);//Setting calendar for start hour of the day
previousDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);//Setting calendar for start minute of the day
previousDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);//Setting calendar for start second of the day

if(selected_cal.getTimeInMillis()>=nextDay.getTimeInMillis()
|| selected_cal.getTimeInMillis()<previousDay.getTimeInMillis()){
        //Show error
}else{
        //Do what you want to do
}
```